# Is some overfitting in a convolutional network alright?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am using resnet50 to classify pictures of flowers from a Kaggle dataset. I would like to clarify some things about my results.

```
 epoch  train_loss  valid_loss  error_rate  time

   0    0.205352    0.226580    0.077546    02:01

   1    0.148942    0.205224    0.074074    02:01
```

These are the last two epochs of training. As you can see, the second epoch shows some overfitting because the train_loss is a good margin lower than the validation loss. Despite the overfitting, the error_rate and the validation loss decreased. I am wondering whether the model had actually improved in spite of the overfitting. Is it better to use the model from epoch 0 or epoch 1 for unseen data? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, "overfitting" is a much abused term nowadays, used to mean almost everything linked to suboptimal performance; nevertheless, and practically speaking, overfitting means something very specific: its telltale **signature** is when your validation loss starts increasing, while your training loss continues decreasing, i.e.:

[image: adapted from Wikipedia]

(Image adapted from Wikipedia entry on [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting))

It's clear than nothing of the sorts happens in your case; the "margin" between your training and validation loss is another story altogether (it is called [generalization gap](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/07/predicting-generalization-gap-in-deep.html)), and does not signify overfitting.

Thus, **in principle**, you have absolutely **no** reason at all to choose a model with higher *validation* loss (i.e. your first one) instead of one with a lower validation loss (your second one).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree that overfitting is sometimes ambiguously defined.